# Is there a mathematical term for telling if $|m|$ is greater than or less than one?

Tags: terminology, slope

A slope can be positive, negative, zero or undefined, but what about the magnitude of the slope? It seems useful to recognize if the slope is steep (greater than $1$) or gentle (less than $1$) as much as it is positive or negative. Those words don't seem to be used in basic algebra, though.

> Is there a mathematical term for telling if $|m|$ is greater than or less than one?

Comment: Indeed, such a notion is deemed unnecessary. Personally, I'd argue on the fact that there is an inherent arbitrarity of choice in selecting $1$, or any other number, as a threshold. Often, arbitrary choices are a symptom of lack of interesting content.

Comment: Really many words in language are unnecessary, and seems noone bothered to give this a name. I am not at all saying that we need a name for it.

Comment: @Davidhuang Please, let me know if my answer is useful for your OP or if you ar easking for something different. Thanks

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

There is not any particular term but observe that $m=\tan \alpha = 1$ for $\alpha = 45°$ thus we can say that $|m|>1$ when the angle to go up or down is greater than $45°$.

Comment: He is probably asking for some english term, sorry i didnt downvote btw.

Comment: @KingTut I'm not sure about your interpretation, I'll wait for a feedback by the asker.

Comment: @KingTut Not also that I've indeed aswered to the OP thus downvote is really not justified in this case, but this is of course only my opinion.

Comment: Yes, some kind of English term, just like positive/negative describes whether it is... you know... positive or negative.

Comment: @gimusi He already said that he did not downwote. In fact I was the one who downvoted since for me it was clear that OP was asking for an English term as it is explained.

Comment: @Levent Yes of course I've fixed the point! I've just aswered that there is not any particular term for that, do you agree?

Comment: Apparently you are right. I guess I just misunderstood your answer. I will not ask how you are sure that there is no such term but I'll remove my downvote (which will be possible if you edit the question).

Comment: @Levent I've answered with respect my knowledge, of course if someone else know that term I will be happy to revise my knowledge and learn something new! Thanks

Comment: "There is not a particolare term." yes you have answered on your part. :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/967291)

Comment: @ArnaudD. Let decide to the asker whether the answer is useful or not, of course it provides an answer since the question is "Does it exist?" and the answer is "No it does not exist", I think it is not a so difficult logical issue to be understood! Maybe you don't like the answer and it can be of course, in this case let provide a better answer than this, it would be more useful than come here to write this kind of comments.

Comment: I've left this comment (through review) because I don't see how mentioning angles brings anything to the question.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Please read again the OP and my answer and explain where and how it does not answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about your arbitrary choice of the absolute value of the slope being less than 1.0, and no reason whatsoever for a special term for it.

You're looking for a new term related to a *range* of derivatives, so you might be interested to learn that the *[subderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative)* of a function at a point $x$ on a one-dimensional function (even one with discontinuous traditional derivative) is the *range* of derivatives consistent with limits at that point.  Thus the subderivative at $x=0$ for this blue function is range $[-1, 1/2]$.  That is, you can draw a line through the point at $x=0$ with any slope in the range $[-1, 1/2]$ and it will touch $f(x)$ only at $x=0$.

[image: subderivative]

The *subgradient* is the multi-dimensional generalization.

Comment: why for the green is m=1/2?

Comment: Because the rise over run is 1/2.  Just notice that the green tangent goes through the points (-1,0) and (0, 1/2).

Comment: Oh yes of course, sorry for the dumb question!